# Get number of records as a grouped time series from a database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table `projects` where users can enter new projects and the user and date_added are recorded (among other fields):

```
|----|------------|--------------|
| id | user_added | date_added   |
|----|------------|--------------|
| 1  | 'person 1' | '2017-01-05' |
| 2  | 'person 2' | '2017-02-10' |
| 3  | 'person 3' | '2017-02-23' |
| 4  | 'person 1' | '2017-03-04' |
| 5  | 'person 3' | '2017-03-31' |
|----|------------|--------------|
```

I wonder if and how i can get the number of projects per month grouped by the user who added the projects. Expected output for the above table:

```
|------------|---------|---------|---------|-----|
| user_added | 2017-01 | 2017-02 | 2017-03 | etc.|
|------------|---------|---------|---------|-----|
| 'person 1' |    1    |    0    |    1    | ... |
| 'person 2' |    0    |    1    |    0    | ... |
| 'person 3' |    0    |    1    |    1    | ... |
|------------|---------|---------|---------|-----|
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the values into columns.  The SQL way is one row per person and per month:

```
select user_added, strftime(date_added, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm, count(*)
from t
group by user_added, strftime(date_added, '%Y-%m')
order by 1, 2;
```

This is the SQLish way to return the result.  You can pivot the values in your application.

The problem with pivoting them in SQL is that you cannot handle an arbitrary number of months.  A SQL query returns a fixed number of columns, whose names have to be specified in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation to do pivoting like this provided you have year-month known beforehand:

```
select user_added,
    count(case 
            when ym = '2017-01'
                then 1
            end) "2017-01",
    count(case 
            when ym = '2017-02'
                then 1
            end) "2017-02",
    count(case 
            when ym = '2017-03'
                then 1
            end) "2017-03",
    . . .
from (
    select user_added,
        strftime(date_added, '%Y-%m') ym
    from your_table
    ) t
group by user_added;
```

If not, then keep the year-month in single column along with it's count for each user:

```
select user_added,
    ym,
    count(*)
from (
    select user_added,
        strftime(date_added, '%Y-%m') ym
    from your_table
    ) t
group by user_added,
    ym;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon Linoff said - you can only pivot within the database when you have a fix number of possible values to pivot into - in your case year-month combinations.

If you stick to your 3 year-month values, it will work like this (and, yes, you will need to hard-wire the year-month values into the column names):

```
WITH
-- input
projects(id,user_added,date_added) AS (
          SELECT 1  , 'person 1' , DATE '2017-01-05' 
UNION ALL SELECT 2  , 'person 2' , DATE '2017-02-10' 
UNION ALL SELECT 3  , 'person 3' , DATE '2017-02-23' 
UNION ALL SELECT 4  , 'person 1' , DATE '2017-03-04' 
UNION ALL SELECT 5  , 'person 3' , DATE '2017-03-31' 
)
,
-- vertical display
vertical_grouped AS (
SELECT
  user_added
, strftime(date_added,'%Y-%M') AS yearmonth
, COUNT(*)                     AS projcount
FROM projects
GROUP BY 
  user_added
, strftime(date_added,'%Y-%M') 
)
SELECT
  user_added
, IFNULL(SUM(CASE yearmonth WHEN '2017-01' THEN projcount END),0) AS "2017-01"
, IFNULL(SUM(CASE yearmonth WHEN '2017-02' THEN projcount END),0) AS "2017-02"
, IFNULL(SUM(CASE yearmonth WHEN '2017-03' THEN projcount END),0) AS "2017-03"
FROM vertical_grouped
GROUP BY
  user_added
;

user_added|2017-01|2017-02|2017-03
person 1  |      1|      0|      1
person 2  |      0|      1|      0
person 3  |      0|      1|      1
```